# I made build sawtooth-seth with the command: docker-compose up --build at fault

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

when I run Sawtooth-Seth is to use the provided docker-compose file. Building Seth requires an environment that has the Docker Engine installed. To start the environment, do:

docker-compose up --build

Error: 
Service 'seth-tp' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c go build -o /project/sawtooth-seth/processor/bin/seth-tp' returned a non-zero code.

bug image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVaeT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncmcd.png)

Comment: when following the following link:https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/seth/releases/latest/getting_started.html and an error occurs